# What causes the dramatic decline in container traffic on the Main-Danube canal?

Tags: infrastructure, transportation

The [Main-Danube Canal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhine%E2%80%93Main%E2%80%93Danube_Canal) is an essential link in the main waterway connecting Western and Easter Europe:

[image: map]
*Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Constanta-Rotterdam_DE.PNG)*

Freight traffic, in particular container traffic, has seen dramatic decline since it was finished in 1992:

[image: container traffic]
*Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Main-Donau-Kanal_Container_001.svg)*
The figure title says: *Transportierte Container (TEU) auf dem Main-Donau-Kanal 1995 bis 2012*, meaning *Transported containers (TEU) on the Main-Danube Canal*.

That is a very spectacular decline, in particular from the peak in 2000 to the low point in 2008.  I understand that water traffic has disadvantages compared to other modes, but that was as true in the 1990s as it is today.  What are some circumstances that have changed between the 1995-2000 period and the early 2010s that could explain this dramatic decline?